# Best way to create reusable templates for different web sites 

Tags: .net, templates

I have created application using TSQL and libraries. Right now I am generating clients content within libraries (hard-coded html with values) but I would like to keep only db logic there.

What is the best way to create reusable .net components which would behave dynamically based on returned DB values? I have not found any normal way how to do it, just copy components across sites manually.

Is there a way to create library which will handle templates, which will import data from db logic and return final result into clients side? So I dont have to hardcode html layout into libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are custom server controls. These are controls that you can put into a separate assembly and use in multiple projects. The learning curve is a bit steep, but it's definitely worth the time to learn.

This should get you started: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx)